# Unable to locate package, can't install software

Tags: installation, apt, package-management

Whenever I try to install any package in Ubuntu 10, I type the command

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

and also the command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

but I get this error every time

```
unable to locate package vlc
```

I tried `sudo apt-get update` again but I still get the same error.

Please help me. Is there something I have to change in the repositories? Please give some suggestions.

Comment: Namasthe. 
could you provide what's the error ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can install vlc very easily in ubuntu .

open your unity dash and type software center . it will give you that named application and click it to open .

there in software center you'll find a search box at left top .

there type as vlc and you will get it .

select it and you'll get an option to install and click that install button .

there you go .

hope that helps .

Comment: this did it for me.  apparently the "universe" source is disabled by default for livecd, so it always said unable to locate package vlc

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html

You'll find ways to install vlc in it. However the site gives the following warning;

Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (lucid)

VLC version 1.0.6 in Ubuntu 10.04 is severely out-of-date. We recommend you install VLC 1.1.x manually.

#### You can manually add the ppa from terminal and install it.

Install VLC 1.1.4 in Ubuntu 10.04

Open the terminal and run the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lucid-bleed/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: @August : Priyanka has mentioned that she uses Ubuntu 10(either 10.04/10.10), I don't think unity comes shipped in by default in these versions.

Comment: @saisivasundar : I agree with your method as "VLC" is available in one of the universe repositories, butthe version for Ubuntu 10.04/10/10 will be severely outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Find these lines in that file.

```
#deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
#deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
#deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
```

Now remove the `#` to include these repositories and save it. The lines should now look like this:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
```

Run `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-* mozilla-plugin-vlc`.

Answer (score -1):

Temporarily change your repositories server to somewhere else and update the apt-get list